# Create hashtable where each value is a vector of many values

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, data-structures, hashtable

I have the following input.txt file which actually has about 150k ids.

```
id    element
 0    1
 0    3
 1    0
 1    1
 1    3
 2    2
 2    4
 3    4
 4    1
```

I want to store the ids as keys and the values in a vector that hold the value for each id. For example in the end I want a hashtable that looks like this.

```
0 -> 1, 3
1 -> 0, 1, 3
2 -> 2, 4
3 -> 4
4 -> 1
```

This is my code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
const int TABLE_SIZE = 128;

class HashEntry
{
    public:
        int key;
        vector< int > values;
        HashEntry(int key, int value)
        {
            this->key = key;
            values.push_back(value);
        }
};

class HashMap
{
    private:
        HashEntry **table;
    public:
        HashMap()
        {
            table = new HashEntry * [TABLE_SIZE];
            for (int i = 0; i< TABLE_SIZE; i++)
            {
                table[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
        /*
         * Hash Function
         */
        int HashFunc(int key)
        {
            return key % TABLE_SIZE;
        }

    void Insert(int key, int value)
    {
            int hash = HashFunc(key);
            table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
    }

    void Show(){

        for (int i=0;i<TABLE_SIZE;i++){
            if (table[i]!=NULL){
                cout << table[i]->key << " : ";
                for(int y = 0; y < table[i]->values.size(); y++) {
                    cout << table[i]->values[y];
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    HashMap hash;
    int key, value;
    while (1)
    {
    cout<<"Enter element to be inserted: ";
    cin>>value;
    cout<<"Enter key at which element to be inserted: ";
    cin>>key;
    hash.Insert(key, value);
    hash.Show();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the console it only shows the last element that I inputted and not all the values. I think the problem is that the HashEntry object is initialized every time and that its members are initialized from the beginning every time. How can I keep HashEntries "static"?

EDIT:
Here is my new code after following Davide Spataro advice. Unfortunately I can't use C++11 so I changed it a bit. Now what is wrong?

```
void Insert(int key, int value)
    {
            int hash = HashFunc(key);
            //check if we already have an `HashEntry` for key
            HashEntry *p = find(key, table[hash]);
            // if yes simply push the value in that `HashEntry`
            if( p->key == -1 ){
                p->values.push_back(value);
                return;
            }
            else{
                //otherwise add an `HashEntry` to the hashtable for key and push a value in it.
                HashEntry *p = new HashEntry(key, value);
                p->values.push_back(value);
                table[hash] = p;
            }

    }

    HashEntry* find(int key, HashEntry *table)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<TABLE_SIZE;i++)
        {
            if (key == table[i].key)
                return &table[i];
            else return new HashEntry(-1,-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Beware that your `HasMap` does not follow the [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and will lead to undefined behavior if you try to (or accidentally) copy it.

Comment: Since you are clearly not opposed to using `std::vector` (you use one for `HashEntry:: values;`) then why not use one for `HashMap::table;`?

Comment: Well, about your insert, shouldnt you add to table[hash] the new value instead of creating a new HashEntry for it?

Comment: Can you guys explain a little better? @Jorge.V if I do that then where will I initialize the HashEntry?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you for your answer. What will I gain by doing that?

Comment: @thelaw You'll gain that you won't need to use `new`/`delete`, you won't need to maintain an owning raw pointer it'll be a first step to avoiding the [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation you have going on.

Comment: @thelaw theorically you have to check if you have already initialized it or not, so that you know if you have to start a list of integers or add a new one. Not really sure what you are doing with the pointers but seeing just a new instance for table there looks suspicious.

Comment: @thelaw `find` is completly wrong. You should return `0` or `NULL` AFTER the `for`!

Comment: What type should find return? I tried it with NULL and 0 and it doesn't work. I also tried with vector but it doesn't work.

Comment: Since you are clearly not opposed to using `std::vector`, why not use `std::unordered_multimap<int, int>`, or `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mainly in your `Insert`. Whenever you find a key that hashes to a particular value you overwirte the `HashEntry` that might be there already creating a new one! This is wrong and also lead to memory leak.

You need also to handle collision. You have only `128` buckets in your hash-table and 150k possible key values. For the pigeon principle, you will end up having more than one `HashEntry` for the same hash value. Your code need to handle this.

Something like the following should be enough as a starting point.

```
 void Insert(int key, int value)
    {
            int hash = HashFunc(key);
            //check if we already have an `HashEntry` for key 
            auto p = find(key, table[hash]);
            // if yes simply push the value in that `HashEntry` 
            if( p != nullptr){
                p->values.push_back(value);
                return;
            }else{
               //otherwise add an `HashEntry` to the hashtable for key and push a value in it.
              auto p = new HashEntry(key, value);
              p->values.push_back(value);
              table[hash] = p;
            }

    }
```

There are other problem like the [rule 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) mentioned in the comments, as you manage raw pointers. (You need to free that memory at some point, don't you?)

Comment: I edited my question following your valuable advice. Can you check it?